# Available Options in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I am thinking about moving over from Forms Central, but I need to confirm some options first.

1. Forms Central allows for "collaborators", that can either be authors or contributors to the forms entry/database. Is this possible for Congnito Forms?
2. Also, can I restrict access for specific users to the Entry info?
3. Is there a "reset" button to clear the old data from the form, so it can be used again for new data submission? I need the form to be available for multiple submission from the same person.

Comment: Questions work best here if you limit yourself to one actual question per question post.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

1. We are working on adding support for multiple users.  Please review this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/FDjI6zak) and provide feedback.
2. Multi-user support will address this too.
3. If a user needs to submit the form multiple times, you can redirect back to the form after submission.